# SQLite multi-threaded inserts to same table causing failure in FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite, foreign-keys, constraints

I have an issue with multi-threaded inserts to the same table. It seems from the error message that the PK is being duplicated:

**Error:**

> FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

**Table:**

```
-- Logs
CREATE TABLE "Logs" (
  "Id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  "Time" DATETIME NOT NULL,
  "Message" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "OtherObjId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(OtherObjId) REFERENCES OtherObjs(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE INDEX IDX_Logs ON Logs (OtherObj);
```

**Code (possibly called async from multiple threads):**

```
public async Task AddLogAsync(Log log) {
  using (var cmd = _conn.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO Logs (Time, Message, OtherObjId) VALUES ('{DateTime.UtcNow}', @message, @OtherObjId);";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", log.Message);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@otherObjId", log.OtherObj.Id);
    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
  }
}
```

My understanding is that the Sqlite db should not have this issue since its running in `serialised` mode  with flag `THREADSAFE=1`. It should queue up the multiple inserts and give each one a different PK.

I am also using the following `PRAGMA`s:

```
PRAGMA synchronous=NORMAL;
PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;
PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
```

I am using SQLite v3.27.2 using the .NET assemblies.

## Update

It seems it is related to the `FOREIGN KEY` (Thanks Tim Biegeleisen. How could I have thought otherwise?). I have done some checking and the record for the foreign key is added well before. Some debug output:

```
Log about to be added for otherObj id 1
otherObj added with id 2
Log about to be added for otherObj id 2
otherObj added with id 3
Log about to be added for otherObj id 3
otherObj added with id 4
Log about to be added for otherObj id 4
otherObj added with id 5
Log about to be added for otherObj id 5
otherObj added with id 6
Log about to be added for otherObj id 6
otherObj added with id 7
Log about to be added for otherObj id 7
otherObj added with id 8
Log about to be added for otherObj id 8
otherObj added with id 9
Log about to be added for otherObj id 9
otherObj added with id 10
Log about to be added for otherObj id 10
otherObj added with id 11
Log about to be added for otherObj id 11
otherObj added with id 12
Log about to be added for otherObj id 12
otherObj added with id 13
Log about to be added for otherObj id 13
otherObj added with id 14
Log about to be added for otherObj id 14
otherObj added with id 15
Log about to be added for otherObj id 15
otherObj added with id 16
Log about to be added for otherObj id 16
Log about to be added for otherObj id 1
Log about to be added for otherObj id 2
Log about to be added for otherObj id 3
otherObj added with id 17
Log about to be added for otherObj id 17
Log about to be added for otherObj id 4
otherObj added with id 18
Log about to be added for otherObj id 18
Log about to be added for otherObj id 5
otherObj added with id 19
Log about to be added for otherObj id 19
Log about to be added for otherObj id 6
otherObj added with id 20
Log about to be added for otherObj id 20
Log about to be added for otherObj id 7
Log about to be added for otherObj id 8
otherObj added with id 461
Log about to be added for otherObj id 461
SQLite error (787): abort at 21 in [INSERT INTO Logs (Time, Message, otherObjId) VALUES ('25/04/2019 11:35:27', @message, @otherObjId);]: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Log about to be added for otherObj id 9
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
An exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code
constraint failed
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

As it can be seen the otherObj id 9 was added long before, yet the failure still happened.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the error message, the failure actually has to do with the *foreign* key in the `Logs` table:

> FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

The failure is most likely happening because one (or more) of your inserts is using an `OtherObjId` value which has no mapping `Id` counterpart in the `OtherObjs` table.  To fix this, you should investigate the sources of the `OtherObjId` values, and ensure that they have parent records in `OtherObjs`.  Perhaps there is a multithreaded problem, or there could be some other cause.

Comment: Please see my update. It is the FOREIGN KEY but the problem is still unexplained.

Comment: @sprocket12 Note that logs alone are not definitive, because there might be a lag between when something happens and when it gets logged.